# Order in which Data Imputation, Outlier removal, Data Transformation should be done?

Tags: data-transformation, outliers, data-imputation, data-preprocessing

While preprocessing data we need to carry out the following steps:

- Missing value Imputation
- Outlier Detection
- Transformation of Data

In what order should we perform these 3 steps while preprocessing the data?

Comment: What makes you say that you need to detect outliers and what do you propose to do with them?

Comment: Detecting outliers will help my classifier to generalize well. It will help in not letting my classifier to be thrown off by outliers

Answer (score 1):

General comment: I think the question indicates a desire for some general algorithm for model fitting. I don't think this is a good idea. Think about each case.

Outlier *detection* (in your text) is useful, but outliers should only be *removed* (your title) when they are errors. And while outliers in the data can be detected in preprocessing, outliers in the model can only be found after running a model.

Variable transformation, in my opinion (other people have different opinions) should only be performed for substantive reasons. If you find that your model doesn't fit, choose another model. However, you can't even tell about it until after you have run a model. Linear regression and other models do not make assumptions about the distribution of variables; some models make assumptions about distribution of errors.  However, if you do decide to transform a variable for substantive reasons, then it is part of preprocessing. (One example of a substantive reason is to take logs of variables that are related to money, because we tend to think about money in a multiplicative way. The difference between a \$100,000 house and a \$200,000 house is like that between a \$1,000,000 house and a \$2,000,000 house, not between a \$1,000,000 and a \$1,100,000 house.) Other models include robust regression and quantile regression.

Missing value imputation is part of preprocessing. Be sure you are doing multiple imputation and not mean imputation or median imputation or something similar. I am not sure it matters whether you do transformation before or after multiple imputation, but my intuition is to transform first.